# Good piano patch for Nord Modular?

Tags: audio, synthesizer, sound, piano

Do you know a good piano patch for the Nord Modular? Not grand piano, but for dance song. A piano sound I like is the piano from the song Someday by Ce Ce Rogers for a reference.